# Wix Conditionally Install Component if Registry Key Exists

Tags: installation, wix

I have a component I need to install only if a registry key exists which means an application has been installed.

I need to assign the value of the registry key (it is a directory) to a property then use this property to copy files from.

I have the following script so far but get an error "The system cannot find the file '[MYTESTDIR]fileToCopy.dat'."

Any help would really be appreciated.

```
<Property Id="MYTESTDIR">
    <RegistrySearch Id="NetFramework20"
            Root="HKLM"
            Key="SOFTWARE\TEST\VALUE\1.00"
            Name="MyName"
            Type="directory" />
</Property>

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="TEST" Name="Test">       
            <Component Id="MyComponent" Guid="E5FF53DE-1739-42c4-BE37-60F810C9CD69">
              <Condition>MYTESTDIR</Condition>
              <File Id="fileToCopy.dat" Name="fileToCopy.dat" Source="[MYTESTDIR]fileToCopy.dat">
                  <CopyFile Id="fileToCopy.datCopy" DestinationProperty="WEBSERVICEBINFOLDER" />
              </File>

        </Directory>            
    </Directory>
</Directory>

<Feature Id="MyFeature" Title="MyFeature" Level="1">
    <ComponentRef Id="MyComponent" />
</Feature>
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on my reading of the Wix Schema documentation, your problem is that you have the [CopyFile](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_copyfile.htm) element nested under a File element.  Ditch the File element and just have the CopyFile sit under the Component:

```
<Component Id="MyComponent" Guid="E5FF53DE-1739-42c4-BE37-60F810C9CD69"> 
  <Condition>MYTESTDIR</Condition> 
  <CopyFile Id="fileToCopy.datCopy" SourceName="[MYTESTDIR]fileToCopy.dat" DestinationProperty="WEBSERVICEBINFOLDER" />
</Component>
```

The way you had it, nested under the File, Wix was looking for the file on your system during the build - rather than setting up a copy command to be run at install time.

Answer (score 1):

`MYTESTDIR` is a windows installer property which will get its value on *the target system when the package is being installed*.

However, you are trying to use this property in a `Source` attribute, which is used to point to files on the system *where the setup package is being build*.

Obviously that is not going to work. Windows installer properties don't even exist while the `Source` attribute is being evaluated, so `Source` can definitely not support such use.

Bryan's answer is the correct solution for what you're trying to do here. Using `CopyFile` under a `File` element is not illegal, but it is intended for copying files which you also install. In this case, you want to copy a file which is already on the target system, so the `File` element is not appropriate.