# How to copy a file only while major upgrade?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

We need to copy a file only when majorupgrade. If fresh install happens it should not copy.

I tried to find File attribute and component attribute which would do it but found none.

How to allow a file to copy when major upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write Custom action to copy the files.

```
<CustomAction Id="QtExecCopyPropertyFileCmd" Property="QtExec64CmdLine" Value="&quot;[SystemFolder]cmd.exe&quot; /c copy &quot;[INSTALL_DIR]\Test.txt&quot; &quot;[BKP_DIR]\Test.txt&quot;"/>
<CustomAction Id="QtExecCopyPropertyFile" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec64" Execute="immediate" Return="check"/>
```

Check previous setup is installed or not using Upgrade property.

```
<Upgrade Id="{YOUR-GUID-HERE}">
  <UpgradeVersion Property="PREVIOUSFOUND" Minimum="1.0.0" IncludeMinimum="yes" Maximum="$(var.Version)" IncludeMaximum="no" />
</Upgrade>
  <Property Id="PREVIOUSFOUND" Secure="yes" />
```

Call the Custom action in Install Execute sequence. It will copy the files in Upgrades only.

```
 <Custom Action="QtExecCopyPropertyFileCmd" After="AppSearch">(NOT Installed) AND (PREVIOUSFOUND&lt;&gt;"")</Custom>
 <Custom Action="QtExecCopyPropertyFile" After="QtExecCopyPropertyFileCmd">(NOT Installed) AND (PREVIOUSFOUND&lt;&gt;"")</Custom>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have component Install Condition which check for existing product and then install. You can Check The following link [Wix Conditionally Install Component if Registry Key Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380800/wix-conditionally-install-component-if-registry-key-exists) for more detail. There insead of filesearch you can do registry search also